# Does a local spacetime symmetry lead to gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

In the case of charge a global $U(1)$ symmetry leads to the conservation of charge, however upgrading the global symmetry to a local symmetry leads to the electromagnetic potential field $A^\mu$ such that:
$$D_\mu =\partial_\mu - iqA_\mu.$$
Since a global space time symmetry leads to the consevation of the energy-momentum tensor $T_{\mu\nu}$ does a local space time symmetry lead to the gravitational field? Where upgrading $\phi(x^\mu+\xi^\mu)$ to $\phi(x^\mu+\xi^\mu(x^\nu))$
$$D_\mu=\partial_\mu+\Gamma^\alpha_{\mu\nu}.$$
(Obviously the indicies don't match here but would the result be in a similar form.)

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46324/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/71476/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/675387/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Not my area of expertise, but I have a vague recollection that making supersymmetry a local symmetry leads to a spin 2 particle i.e. the graviton.

Comment: @JohnRennie I haven't looked into supersymmetry yet, is there any articles showing how that making supersymmetry a local symmetry leads to the graviton

Comment: Have a look at [the Wikipedia article on supergravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supergravity) to get started. That should lead you to more technical articles.

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: **yes**, one can view General Relativity (GR) as a gauge theory, see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.02627) as a reference. It's not straightforward: the fields of GR are tensors, have many more indices, and require more constraints and identities to create a consistent theory of gravity.

Nevertheless, pay attention to the fact that a local symmetry doesn't "lead" to a physical field: not for gravity, nor for electromagnetism (not *a priori*, at least).
The second chapter of the linked paper provides a detailed explanation of the gauging procedure, but the main idea is: I have some fields ($\phi$), they have a global symmetry, meaning my Lagrangian is invariant under a global transformation, that's cool. I'd like to make my transformation local, my fields seem fine, but my Lagrangian isn't invariant anymore, that's not cool, I have extra terms. If I added another field ($A_\mu$), which transforms in a particular way, I could reabsorb the extra terms, and the said field can be added without bothering what's already in the Lagrangian, everything cool again. Moreover, I can add a kinetic term ($F_{\mu\nu}$) for this field, meaning this field can propagate on its own! Super cool. *Still*, this doesn't mean that the new field is *physical*, maybe the theory described by the Lagrangian just isn't a gauge theory and I'm doing everything wrong.
Then someone builds a LHC and finds a particle that could be described by the said field. *NOW* we can say that this field is physical.